# Upgrade to 18.10 now I need recovery mode to boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.10

After upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10 everything went well and booted on first boot. On subsequent boots it will hang on the ubuntu splash (no movement of circles). If I hit escape and select recovery mode 4.18 kernel, then just select continue everything boots and works fine. I have done the following to troubleshoot:

- added nomodeset to grub.
- journalctl --list-boots
- journalctl -b-1  (I can share this output if it would be helpful)

There were a number of errors listing... one fatal error:

```
Nov 21 12:14:56 eden-Z87X-UD4H systemd[2214]: gpgconf: fatal error (exit status 1)
```

However that error was about 75% down the file.... not sure if it is the main issue.

I am running Nvidia and it appears to be running inside the recovery mode, Running 
`lspci -knn | grep -A3 VGA`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] [10de:13c2] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] [3842:3979]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: I'd like to add that I have removed quite and splash from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and I still see the splash and no terminal output unless I boot in recovery mode... odd.